# CLI v2.0.1-beta.28 proxies.json issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I add to my project proxies.json file however after that runtime is unable to start with exception. Any ideas? I already look thru GitHub issues without any luck.

At the and I add gist with *.csproj and proxies.json file for reproduction.

Thanks a lot

```
[02/06/2018 17:10:57] Initializing Azure Function proxies
[02/06/2018 17:10:57] Error processig configuration of Function Proxies
[02/06/2018 17:10:57]
Function host is not running.
[02/06/2018 17:10:59] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[02/06/2018 17:10:59] Autofac: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ProxyHandler (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Runtime.ProxyHandler], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception fordetails. Registration: Activator = ApiInspectorHandler (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Runtime.Handlers.ApiInspectorHandler], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DebugLogStorageService (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Runtime.Logging.IDebugLogService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = FileSystemStorage (DelegateActivator), Services = [DetailedTrace (Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Common.Infra.IBlobStorage)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime,Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> Access to the path '/Users/maciejgos\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace' is denied. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.). Autofac: An error occurredduring the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ApiInspectorHandler (ReflectionActivator),Services = [Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Runtime.Handlers.ApiInspectorHandler], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DebugLogStorageService (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Runtime.Logging.IDebugLogService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = FileSystemStorage (DelegateActivator), Services = [DetailedTrace (Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Common.Infra.IBlobStorage)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> Access to the path '/Users/maciejgos\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace' is denied. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.). Autofac: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator= DebugLogStorageService (DelegateActivator), Services = [Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Runtime.Logging.IDebugLogService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = FileSystemStorage (DelegateActivator), Services = [DetailedTrace (Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Common.Infra.IBlobStorage)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> Access to the path '/Users/maciejgos\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace' is denied. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.). Autofac: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = FileSystemStorage (DelegateActivator), Services = [DetailedTrace (Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Proxy.Common.Infra.IBlobStorage)], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared,Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> Access to the path '/Users/maciejgos\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace' is denied. (See inner exception for details.). System.IO.FileSystem: Access to the path '/Users/maciejgos\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace' is denied. Permission denied.
[02/06/2018 17:10:59] Stopping Host
```

https://gist.github.com/maciejgos/4bc0650aa72dd94e61b798e94da83aeb

One more remark which I observe today. When I add empty proxies.json file everthing is ok as soon as I start adding json structure {}

For easier reproduction I add sample source code for reproduction https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkqjecaXrgd9469n7iG3ui-4tAnnoA

Azure Functions CLI is installed on macOS using [homebrew](https://brew.sh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a httptrigger template and copy files in your gits, but can't reproduce your entire exception on my side.

I got only `Error processing configuration of Function Proxies` and host started successfully.

This single error message is caused by `"backendUri": ""` in `proxies.json` file. This parameter should be deleted instead of being set to an empty string since you set response directly in proxy. See the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies#responseOverrides).

Also I see  `Access to the path '/Users/YourName\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace' is denied` in your exception message, so you could try to run your cli as administartor/superuesr.

**Update**

Your sample works well on my side(OS:Windows) without running cli as admin.

If I use windows cmd, it doesn't create folder like yours. While if I use git bash, `C:\Users\UserName\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace` is created.

So I guess, to start host with proxy on MacOS, it might be required to run cli `2.0.1-beta.28` as superuser. Have opened an issue on [azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2942). You can track it for further info.

**Update 2**

This problem has been fixed and in cli 2.0.1-beta.35, the proxy should work as expected.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I check your solution however without success. I attach sample source code for reproduction https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkqjecaXrgd9469n7iG3ui-4tAnnoA

Comment: @maciejgos Have tested your sample, it works on my side. See my update.

Comment: Thanks. As last test I execute func start as superuser and it works. So issue is related to macOS. Problem is only related to proxies functionality

Comment: @maciejgos So everything works if you run cli as superuser? No error or exception when host start and function get triggered?

Comment: Almost. One small issue I see is that CLI doesn't recognise proxies custom routes and I need to type them manually. But this is minor issue. The main problem is need to run CLI as root.

Comment: @maciejgos The minor issue also happens on my side. Not sure if it's by design that cli shows proxy name instead of route. Have added this extra question to that issue. Let's wait for azure team's reply.

Comment: @maciejgos This problem has been fixed(including the minor one) in cli 2.0.1-beta.35, could you accept my answer to close this question?

Comment: Great news. Thanks a lot